# Prove that $\left| \sin z \right| \leq 1$ implies $ \left|\operatorname{Im} z\right| \leq \ln\left(\sqrt{2}+1\right)$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Prove that if $\left| \sin z \right| \leq 1$, then $$ \left|y\right| \leq \ln\left(\sqrt{2}+1\right) .$$

I am not familiar with hyperbolic function before learning complex analysis but in order to deal with questions like this, hyperbolic functions do seem useful!

For example,

> $$\sin (x+iy) = \sin x \cosh y + i \sinh y \cos x$$

With further simplification, we can also show

> $$\left| \sin z \right| = \sqrt{\cosh^2y - \cos ^2 x}$$

I get the sense that I am close, but how should I get the range of $y$ from these? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$\implies\cosh^2y-\cos^2x\le1$$

$$\implies\cosh^2y\le\cos^2x+1\le1+1$$

As $\cosh y\ge1,$

$$\implies\cosh y\le\sqrt2$$

Now $2\cosh y=e^y+e^{-y}$

Comment: then we get $e^{y} + e^{-y} \leq 2\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: @LeeKM, Solve $$e^y+e^{-y}=2\sqrt2$$ for $y$  Use $$(x-a)(x-b)\le0\implies a\le x\le b$$

Comment: i got it now! thx!!

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there: Squaring and rearranging gives
$$\cosh^2 y = |\sin z|^2 + \cos^2 x, $$
but $0 \leq \cos^2 x \leq 1$ and by hypothesis $|\sin z|^2 \leq 1$, so
$$\cosh^2 y \leq 1 + 1 = 2 ,$$
and hence $$1 \leq \cosh y \leq \sqrt{2}. $$
Now, use that $$\operatorname{arcosh} u = \log\left(u + \sqrt{u^2 - 1}\right) ,$$ which in particular is an increasing function.

Comment: How do we obtain the last equality?

Comment: Since $\operatorname{arcosh}$ is increasing (to see this, we can simply show that its derivative is positive), we have that $$\operatorname{arcosh} \cosh y \leq \operatorname{arcosh}(\sqrt{2}) =  \log\left[\left(\sqrt{2}\right) + \sqrt{\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^2 - 1} \right] = \log\left(\sqrt{2} + 1\right).$$ Since $\operatorname{arcosh} \cosh y$ is $y$ for $y \geq 0$ and $-y$ for $y \leq 0$, we have $\operatorname{arcosh} \cosh y = |y|$.